# SQL Server: SUM Task Cumulative Work by Day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having issues with the Task Cumulative Work hours. Please see below for details:

I have this Data (Cumulative Hours by day):

[image]

I have this SQL Statement:

[image]

These are my Actual Results:
[image]

This is my desired Results (Which is the cumulative hours for all phases):

[image]

Please any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please use the actual code, not screenshots.

Comment: please post table schema, sample data and expected result

Comment: I down voted because you posted images of code, rather than a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` operator

```
select 'Project_1' as ProjectTitle, TimeByDay, sum(Work) as TaskCumulativeWork
from table t cross apply (
        values ('2017-07-04', [2017-07-04]),
                . . . 
               ('2017-07-12', [2017-07-12])) t1(TimeByDay, Work)
group by TimeByDay
order by TimeByDay desc;
```

However, I would also recommend to fix the data model.